# Compare a GitHub gist with its forks

Tags: github, diff, gist

I found an interesting gist on GitHub, tried it out, and found a bug. I noticed that there are several forks of the gist, so I wondered if any of them have fixed the bug I found. I can see the list of forks, and some of them are marked as modified, but I can't see how to tell what the differences are between the forks and the original. Is there a way to view the diffs?

As an example, I found a [Markov text generator](https://gist.github.com/agiliq/131679). I can see the [list of forks](https://gist.github.com/agiliq/131679/forks), but each one just shows the current version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It wasn't too hard, but it took me a while to realize what I was looking at. The revisions of a fork include the revisions of the original, so you can see the differences by looking at any revisions after the gist was forked.

For example, Eckanakar's fork has [several revisions](https://gist.github.com/Eckankar/360212/revisions) that you can see changes in.